# Can a field onchange look for changes without user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way for onchange or another function to look for a change without user input? I have a javascript function that user innerHTML to change some fields in an contenteditable table. The Update function works, it updates based off variables in the script. Some fields get updated and some don't. I use the function below to look for a change already in the table and that works because If I understand correct there is no correct onchange on a html5 contenteditable div or table. How can if some of the cells in the table update without user input how can it run a script? It would need to be in like the function below.

```
$("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
//my update stuff here works

}
```

Hope it all makes sense. Thank You

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you create a demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as shown in the demo below. And sure you can trigger any event programmatically, by calling `.trigger( 'event' )` on the desired DOM element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
  })
  .trigger( 'change' ); ///<<<==== this triggers 'change' on DOM ready
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: That didin't work. I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: What do you mean *that didn't work*? Do you have a demo showing the issue?

Comment: No it's on my localhost. Let me create one on JSFiddle. Give me a minuet. Thank You

Comment: I got it to work. $this.myfield('valuechanged').trigger('change');